# Consume Protobuf message off Kafka topic using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, protobuf-java

I want to consume a Protobuf message off a Kafka topic / Apache Camel route. I want to consume the message, convert it to an entity class and persist in a database. I am struggling to find the syntax for consuming the message. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
@Test
void produceMessage() {
    DataChangedEvent event = DataChangedEvent.newBuilder().setId("123").build();
    template.sendBody("direct:kafkaEventTopic", event);
}

@Component
public class EventRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("kafkaEventTopic")
                .routeId("eventRoute")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "About to process event: ${body}")
//                .unmarshal().protobuf(ProtobufLibrary.Jackson, JsonNode.class).
                .unmarshal().protobuf(new JacksonProtobufDataFormat(DataChangedEvent.class))
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "out: ${body}");
    }
}
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: defaultInstance as there isn't a setter method with same type: org.apache.camel.component.jackson.protobuf.JacksonProtobufDataFormat nor type conversion possible: The argument for setDefaultInstance should be subClass of com.google.protobuf.Message

Comment: Could you please also add the code of your class `DataChangedEvent`?

Comment: The from endpoint of your route doesn't seem to be correct, I guess it should rather be `direct:kafkaEventTopic` or `kafka:EventTopic`?